# Can Apple On Demand Resources be used in a Cocoapod

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to optionally include a large number of .zip files in an Xcode project.  These files are only needed in the project during certain types of builds and are essentially resources for a specific part of the app.  These files are large and require the use of Apple's On Demand Resources.  I would like to move them into a pod and optionally include that pod when needed.

Each resource requires a resource tag as shown here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/Tagging.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015083-CH3-SW1

Is there a way to use on demand resource tags in a cocoapod?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for On Demand Resources was added for CocoaPods 1.11.0 which is currently available in beta. See the details at https://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.11.0-beta/

Comment: That is fantastic.  Any idea when the beta may be released?

Comment: CocoaPods 1.11.0.beta.2 is available.
To update use: `gem install cocoapods --pre`

Comment: Thank you for that.  I was wondering when 1.11 goes from beta to released.

Comment: CocoaPods does not make predictions about release dates. The timing will depend on beta feedback and volunteer interest/availability.